# Paraphrase "back to basics experiments"?

Tags: paraphrasing, adjective-phrases, attributives

> […] such **back to basics experiments** are precisely what a pheromone researcher at Oxford University argues for in another paper just published in the proceedings of the Royal Society […]

How should I paraphrase the bold part for homework?

1. > return to traditional experiments
2. > back to fundamental experiments

Comment: What's the paraphrase for? Are you rewriting the passage to make a better impression or be clearer, or trying to understand it for yourself, or what?

Comment: Hello!! and thanks for reading my post. it is my homework. it is taken from an article about a research of Human Pheromones, the teacher want me to paraphrase the sentence in capital letters. i wrote down "return to traditional experiments " or " back to fundamental experiments" but i dont know if it is correct or no

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct.  "Back to basics" plays a role of an adjective and defines "experiments".  It's not "back" "to" "basics experiments", it's "back to basics" "experiments".

With this explanation, try it again.

Comment: +1. Yes, it's an [attributive adjective phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase). One can also join the three words with hyphens: "In order to help us understand the topics better, our teacher loves to make **back-to-basics** experiments"

Comment: could be "old experiments"? "first experiments"?

Comment: No.  Look up the definition of "back to basics".